# Cannot access response data object

Tags: javascript, react-native

I getted the object below from my API and setted in my state.

When I print `console.log(this.state.categories.data)` I have this result:

```
[{"description": "Meditações com foco na Respiração", "id": 1, "name": "Respiração"}, {"description": "Meditações que projetam atenção nos sentidos e percepções do corpo, do ambiente.", "id": 2, "name": "Sensitiva"}, {"description": "Meditação ativa, pode ser feita em durante outras atividades", "id": 3, "name": "Ativa"}]
```

But when I try access the objects, I get errors.

```
console.log(this.state.categories.data[0]) 
undefined is not object
```

I tryed use JSON.parse() too, but get Unexpected indentifier "undefined".

Whats happen?

Comment: Just tested this one and i am able to access the object by doing `data[0]` it works fine.